# Swf is taking too much time to load, how do I make it faster?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash, flashcatalyst

I developed  a project in flex and catalyst and the size of swf is too much, sometimes its take too much time to load. Product is already ready, so i cant change in code too much. Please help me to solve this issue. one more thing sometimes its load very fast and sometimes its take lots of time. Why its like that?

Comment: Either size of your application will be too heavy or you can avoid this by dividing your screens to separate modules and load it when ever you want them.

Comment: There is no trick that will magically reduce and optimize all the code that's been generated by Catalyst, if that's what you're after.

Comment: Its size is 4.6 MB, @rajesh.adhi can i divide in screens without changing lots of code

Comment: I think 4.6Mb is not that heavy if we consider the current network speed, but in a slower network the loading will be slower for sure. Dividing the screen and doing applications as modules these things should be taken in to consideration when you start planning on your application architecture now it will be bit tough task for you. Are you sure you are not using any un wanted embed statements in your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer is that there's no quick solution.  There are several things you can do like caching RSLs (using the Adobe signed one), creating your own RSLs, dividing your application into modules, remove all embedded media and make it load on demand, use vectors (FXG) instead of bitmap files (png, jpg, etc) and make sure you don't add things that aren't needed.

All of these can make an application load faster and be much more responsive.  The problem is that it's not a quick solution and needs quite a bit of architecting.  Normally, you start this from the beginning of your project.  From the sounds of it, you didn't know most of these concepts and you've added everything to one massive swf file (including RSLs).

You've got a long road ahead of you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any query made to server? In that case it's better to check the server capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You're exporting a release build, not a debug build, right?

You can download [SWFWire Inspector](http://www.swfwire.com/inspector) to examine what's in your file, and why it's so big.  Like J_A_X said, it's probably mostly embedded assets, which you can try to load separately.

*Disclaimer: I wrote this application*